# View within Touchable not rendered on Android

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have created a custom button component that should respond to touches. It works as expected on iOS, however on Android it doesn't show up at all. While trying to find the cause of this issue.

I created two snacks on expo to demonstrate the issue. The first is the element wrapped in a Touchable element, and the second is the element without it.

In the first snack, it works as expected in iOS, however it is not shown on Android.

In the second snack, it appears as expected on both, however it is not clicking

https://snack.expo.io/@shepherdjerred/button-with-touchable
https://snack.expo.io/@shepherdjerred/button-without-touchable

Answer (score 1):

For the first snack, add style={{flex: 1}} to the first view component.  Flex adjusts a component based on the amount of space available in the application's screen.

```
return (
  <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPressIn={this.handlePressIn.bind(this)}
    onPressOut={this.handlePressOut.bind(this)}>
    <View style={{flex: 1}}>
      <View
        style={[
          this.stylesheet.buttonLayer,
          this.stylesheet.buttonShadow
        ]}>
      </View>
      <View
        style={[
          this.stylesheet.buttonLayer,
          this.stylesheet.buttonDepth
        ]}>
      </View>
      <View
        style={[
          this.stylesheet.buttonLayer,
          this.stylesheet.buttonTop,
          this.state.isPressed ? this.stylesheet.buttonTopPushed : this.stylesheet.buttonTopUnpushed
        ]}>
      </View>
    </View>
  </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
);
}
```

For the second snack, the React Native website has two ways of creating buttons or components that can be touched.

References:

- Facebook Inc. "Height and Width". React Native. 
  https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/height-and-width.html
  (accessed April 2, 2018).
- Facebook Inc. "Handling Touches". React Native.
  https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/handling-touches.html
  (accessed April 2, 2018).
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/44063868/8121551 (accessed April 2,
  2018).